# Updating SQL server table from Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, updating

how can keep Update SQL Server Tables from Oracle? I want SQL tables updating every day or after 24 hours. but I can't write Trigger on Oracle because the Oracle database is not mine and I just use it. so what should I do? notice: I can code in Asp.Net

Comment: As you can't *push* from Oracle to MS SQL Server (database isn't yours, you can't do anything there), then *pull* data from Oracle. Oracle has a *database link* which enables you to communicate between databases. Heterogeneous services help you access databases that belong do different vendors. Now, what does MS SQL Server offer in that *niche*, I wouldn't know.

Comment: To pull from the SQL Server side you could use a linked server (bad idea) or use SSIS. Please provide more details - is it acceptable to build a pull solution in SQL Server? How large are the Oracle tables? Do they have a field that will let you do incremental processing?